# Оптимизация запроса в таблице MySQL с 300 миллионами записей

Tags: mysql, оптимизация

Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE `tblNewPricesData` (
  `SymbolID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `AssesstmentDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `BateID` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `DateOperation` date NOT NULL,
  `Value` double NOT NULL,
  `NewID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `isActual` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  UNIQUE KEY `indexNewData` (`SymbolID`,`AssesstmentDate`,`BateID`),
  KEY `NewID` (`NewID`),
  KEY `indexActual` (`isActual`),
  KEY `indexSBD` (`SymbolID`,`BateID`,`AssesstmentDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE ( EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM AssesstmentDate))
(PARTITION before1979 VALUES LESS THAN (197901) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1979_01 VALUES LESS THAN (197902) ENGINE = InnoDB,
.....................
PARTITION p2021_12 VALUES LESS THAN (202201) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

В таблице 300 миллионов записей
Таблица разбита на разделы помесячно.
Данные в таблицу добавляются каждый день. Обновляются тоже каждый день но только на одну дату.

Есть запрос к базе данных

```
SELECT nn.SymbolID, DATE(MAX(nn.AssesstmentDate)) as LAD from sarusdb_prices.tblNewPricesData nn
where nn.SymbolID IN (23,300,...,3045) AND nn.AssesstmentDate <= '2019-02-01 23:59:59' group by nn.SymbolID
```

Результаn EXPLAIN

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------------+----------+---------+------+------+-----------------
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                           | key      | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------------+----------+---------+------+------+-----------------
|  1 | SIMPLE      | nn    | range | indexNewData,NewID,indexActual,indexSBD | indexSBD | 4       | NULL | 6885 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------------+----------+---------+------+------+-----------------
```

Для четырехсот (400) символов (SymbolID) т.е. список IN в запросе, скорость выполнения запроса варьируется от 4 до 7 секунд, в зависимости от нагрузки MySQL. Пробовались принудительные индексы чрез FORCE INDEX indexSBD, indexNewData. Время примерно одинаковое.
Возможно ли как-нибудь снизить время до 1 секунды или это уже предел? Спасибо.

Comment: Выражение партиционирования не совпадает с выражением в условии отбора запроса - скорее всего, сканятся все партиции.

Comment: @Akina - Да вы правы

Comment: Добавьте `AND EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM AssesstmentDate) <= EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '2019-02-01 23:59:59')` - при всём идиотизме из-за наличия условия прямого сравнения, без EXTRACT, оно отсечёт неподходящие партиции.

Comment: @Akina Добавил уже вычисленное выражение AND EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM AssesstmentDate) <= 201902. Результат тоже самый. EXPLAIN показывает что поиск все равно идет во всех партициях.

Comment: Для меня вообще, честно говоря, загадка, нафига потребовалось использовать выражение для партиционирования вместо вполне себе честных литералов. Ни хрена ж не видать! и, может, у затрагивания ненужных партиций оттуда же ноги растут...

Comment: @Akina Что вы имеет ввиду? У вас есть другой вариант партицирования? Меня все устравивало. Скорость добавления и обновления данных хорошая. Я хотел чтобы данные "резались" по месяцам. Возможно есть другое мудрое решение?

Comment: `PARTITION BY RANGE (AssesstmentDate) (PARTITION before1979 VALUES LESS THAN ('1979-01-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p1979_01 VALUES LESS THAN ('1979-02-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,...`. Прямая ссылка на поле. Никаких функций. А ещё - нужен, вроде бы, индекс по `AssesstmentDate` (или чтобы оно хотя бы префиксом было), впрочем, тут могу ошибаться.